# R: count word occurrence by row and create variable

Tags: r, count

new to R. I am looking to create a function to count the number of rows that contain 1 or more of the following words ("foo", "x", "y") from a column.

I then want to label that row with a variable, such as "1".

I have a data frame that looks like this:
a->

```
 id     text        time   username
 1     "hello x"     10     "me"
 2     "foo and y"   5      "you"
 3     "nothing"     15     "everyone"
 4     "x,y,foo"     0      "know"
```

The correct output should be:

count: 3
new data frame

a2 ->

```
id     text        time   username        keywordtag  
 1     "hello x"     10     "me"          1
 2     "foo and y"   5      "you"         1
 3     "nothing"     15     "everyone"     
 4     "x,y,foo"     0      "know"        1
```

Any hints on how to do this would be appreciated!

Comment: What code have you tried so far to generate this new variable?

Comment: What are the valid separators between words in your `text` variable? So far, it looks like words can be separated by spaces or commas. Are there other valid separators?

Comment: separators can be both spaces and commas (or other punctuation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably much safer than my previous answer.

```
> string <- c("foo", "x", "y")
> a$keywordtag <- 
      (1:nrow(a) %in% c(sapply(string, grep, a$text, fixed = TRUE)))+0
> a
#   id      text time username keywordtag
# 1  1   hello x   10       me          1
# 2  2 foo and y    5      you          1
# 3  3   nothing   15 everyone          0
# 4  4   x,y,foo    0     know          1
```

Comment: Note as with @TylerRinker's solution that this would match the word "exciting" even though (based on my interpretation) that is not the desired functionality, since the OP is looking to match words.

Comment: Anyone know how to do a fuzzy match of this? So to avoid any punctuation, spacing, etc?

Comment: `fixed = TRUE` takes care of that. It will only match exactly the elements of `string`

Comment: To augment the keywordtag to instead label each member of the string as a unique identifier?

Comment: Can someone add commentary on how this is working? I read it as: logical test, apply to dataframe, where string is matched in the text column. Then convert to integer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 approaches with **base** and  **qdap**:

```
a <- read.table(text='id     text        time   username
 1     "hello x"     10     "me"
 2     "foo and y"   5      "you"
 3     "nothing"     15     "everyone"
 4     "x,y,foo"     0      "know"', header=TRUE)
```

**# Base**

```
a$keywordtag <- as.numeric(grepl("\\b[foo]\\b|\\b[x]\\b|\\b[y]\\b", a$text))
a
```

**# qdap**

```
library(qdap)
terms <- termco(gsub("(,)([^ ])", "\\1 \\2", a$text), 
    id(a), list(terms = c(" foo ", " x ", " y ")))
a$keywordtag <- as.numeric(counts(terms)[[3]] > 0)
a
```

**# output**

```
##   id      text time username keywordtag
## 1  1   hello x   10       me          1
## 2  2 foo and y    5      you          1
## 3  3   nothing   15 everyone          0
## 4  4   x,y,foo    0     know          1
```

The base approach is bar far more eloquent and simple.

**# EDIT** (borrowing from Richard I believe this is most generalizable and undestandable):

```
words <- c("foo", "x", "y")
regex <- paste(sprintf("\\b[%s]\\b", words), collapse="|")
within(a,{
    keywordtag = as.numeric(grepl(regex, a$text))
})
```

Comment: I added a less than ideal `gsub` fix to the `qdap` approach.  I like the base approach here.

Comment: and if we need to have each word link to a number? (i.e, foo=1, x=2, and so forth?)

Comment: This sounds like a new question.  If it is please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to splitting a vector of strings on multiple delimiters and checking if any of the tokens are in your set of desired words. You can split on multiple delimiters using `strsplit` (I'll use comma and whitespace, since your question doesn't specify the full set of delimiters for your problem), and I'll use `intersect` to check if it contains any word in your set:

```
m <- c("foo", "x", "y")
a$keywordtag <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(a$text), ",|\\s"),
                                         function(x) length(intersect(x, m)) > 0)))
a
#   id      text time username keywordtag
# 1  1   hello x   10       me          1
# 2  2 foo and y    5      you          1
# 3  3  exciting   15 everyone          0
# 4  4   x,y,foo    0     know          1
```

I've included "exciting", which is a word that contains "x" but that isn't listed as a match by this approach.

Comment: I added a better approach with qdap and base and another that takes Richards as well and makes what I believe to be the most generalizable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of Tyler Rinker's answer:

`within(a,{keywordtag = as.numeric(grepl("foo|x|y", fixed = FALSE, a$keywordtag))})`